# Solving system of equation based on RSA

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

I have got 4 variables $n$, $x$, $y$, and $z$:

Here, $n =  p\cdot q$ with $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes

\begin{align}
x &= m^p \bmod n\\
y &= m^q \bmod n\\
z &= m^n \bmod n\\
\end{align}
How can I find $m$?

Comment: Thanks kelalaka, I knew [that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/101747/1) from your euler's theorem hint. But I find it hard to find $m$ since the number is too large. What I have found:
$$\begin{align}c\cdot m&\equiv a\cdot b&\pmod n\\a\cdot b&\equiv k&\pmod n&\quad\text{(k found)}\end{align}$$
So is there any more convenient ways to find $m$?

Comment: @NewbieBoy: Python has built-in support for big integers and has the [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function that handles modular arithmetic, including modular inverses in recent versions. Java standard libraries have the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/c.html) class which also has the necessary functionality. Independently: what you mean by $a$, $b$ and $k$ is unclear in the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a past CTF we can provide a guide to solve it.

[Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) states that if $\gcd(m,n) =1$ with $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ then

$$m^{\varphi (n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \label{5}\tag{1}$$

and $\varphi$ is  [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). In the case of $n= pq$ where  $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes $$\varphi (n) = (p-1)(q-1)$$

Now, a little arithmetic;

\begin{align}
\varphi (n) &= (p-1)(q-1)\\
\varphi (n) &= pq-p- q +1\\
\varphi (n) &= n - p - q +1\\
\end{align}

Now use this on equation $\ref{5}$

$$m^{n - p - q +1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

<s>The rest should be obvious</s>.

$$\frac{m^{n}\cdot m}{m^p\cdot m^q} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

The rest should be more obvious.

> $$m \equiv \frac{m^p\cdot m^q}{m^{n}} \pmod{n} \label{lab1}\tag{2}$$ People working on CTF can directly use equation $\ref{lab1}$. 
> To reach this, however, we need to make sure that $m^n$ has an inverse to modulo $n$.
>   The only elements that are non-invertible are  $kp+n\mathbb Z$ (for $0<k<q$) and $kq+n\mathbb Z$ (for $0<k<p$) since to have inverse one must have $\gcd(a,n) =1$ and this is not the case for the multiples of $p$ and $q$ ( actually, there are exactly $\varphi(n)$ invertible elements in $\mathbb Z$.
>  Therefore $m^n$ is invertible iff $ p \nmid m$ or $q \nmid m$. For this, the blow SageMath code is verification that for some $m$, there is no inverse of $m^n$.

> The rest is a big spoiler since it includes SageMath code!! To see it, you need to [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/101747/edit) this answer.

Since this is a CTF, one can make sure that the CTF organizers selected the $m$ invertible so that CTF players can have solutions!

Comment: Our community Guide on [Capture the flag questions](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1106/18298). Why the downvote? Could downvoter explain the reason for this?

Comment: Moderator note: an appropriate place to make that explanation seems to be a new answer to the meta-question linked. [update] There is such [new answer](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1638/555).